# Python Mechanical soup - webscraping - Unable to open pagination link in .aspx form, even after modifying '__EVENTTARGET' and '__EVENTARGUMENT'

Tags: asp.net, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination, mechanicalsoup

Can someone help me in providing the instructions on how to open the pagination link in aspx form using mechanicalsoup , I updated the __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT , but still it is opening the current page , instead of opening up the next page.

```
            form = browser.select_form('#form1')
            form["__EVENTTARGET"] = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvData"
            form["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = "Page$2"
            print(form.form.find("input", {"name": "__EVENTTARGET"}).attrs)
            print(form.form.find("input", {"name": "__EVENTARGUMENT"}).attrs)
            new_response = browser.submit_selected()
            print(new_response.content)
```

Comment: Can you share URL? ASP(x) pages are sometimes tricky to parse.

Comment: below is the url , I am trying to parse, https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/List_Scrips.aspx'

Comment: To be more specific, below are the select values, form.set_select({'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddSegment' : 'Equity', \
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlStatus' : 'Active' , \
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlIndustry': 'Banks',      
                })

Comment: Andrej Kesely, Thank you very much for your inputs, I modified it accordingly for my scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script goes from page 1 to 9 and gets the information:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/List_Scrips.aspx'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

data = {}
for i in soup.select('input'):
    data[i['name']] = i.get('value', '')

for page in range(1, 10):  # <--- increase the number of pages here
    print('Page {}...'.format(page))
    print('-' * 80)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data).content, 'html.parser')

    for tr in soup.select('tr.TTHeader ~ tr:not(:has(td[colspan]))'):
        print(tr.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))

    data = {}
    for i in soup.select('input'):
        data[i['name']] = i.get('value', '')

    data['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvData'
    data['__EVENTARGUMENT']  = 'Page${}'.format(page+1)
    del data['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit']
```

Prints:

```
Page 1...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
500002 ABB ABB India Limited Active B 2.00 INE117A01022 Heavy Electrical Equipment Equity
500003 AEGISLOG AEGIS LOGISTICS LTD. Active A 1.00 INE208C01025 Oil Marketing & Distribution Equity
500004 TPAEC TORRENT POWER AEC LTD. Delisted B 10.00 INE424A01014 Equity
500005 AKARLAMIN AKAR LAMINATORS LTD. Delisted XD 10.00 INE984C01013 Iron & Steel Products Equity
500006 ALPHADR ALPHA DRUG INDIA LTD. Delisted B 10.00 INE256B01026 Equity
500008 AMARAJABAT AMARA RAJA BATTERIES LTD. Active A 1.00 INE885A01032 Auto Parts & Equipment Equity
500009 AMBALALSA AMBALAL SARABHAI ENTERPRISES LTD. Active X 10.00 INE432A01017 Pharmaceuticals Equity
500010 HDFC HOUSING DEVELOPMENT FINANCE CORP.LTD. Active A 2.00 INE001A01036 Housing Finance Equity
500011 AMRTMIL-BDM AMRUT INDUSTRIES LTD. Delisted Z 10.00 NA Equity
500012 ANDHRAPET ANDHRA PETROCHEMICALS LTD. Active X 10.00 INE714B01016 Commodity Chemicals Equity
500013 ANSALAPI ANSAL PROPERTIES & INFRASTRUCTURE LTD. Active T 5.00 INE436A01026 Realty Equity
500014 UTIQUE Utique Enterprises Ltd Active X 10.00 INE096A01010 Finance (including NBFCs) Equity
500015 ICICIDM ICICI LTD. Delisted B 10.00 INE005A01011 Equity
500016 ARUNAHTEL ARUNA HOTELS LTD. Active XT 10.00 INE957C01019 Hotels Equity
500018 ARPOLDM ARPOLDM Delisted B 10.00 INE035A01018 Equity
500019 BOR BANK OF RAJASTHAN LTD. Delisted B 10.00 INE320A01014 Banks Equity
500020 BOMDYEING BOMBAY DYEING & MFG.CO.LTD. Active A 2.00 INE032A01023 Textiles Equity
500021 ASINCOF ASINCOF Delisted Z 10.00 NA Equity
500023 ASIANHOTNR Asian Hotels (North) Limited Active B 10.00 INE363A01022 Hotels Equity
500024 ASSAMCO Assam Company (India) Limited Delisted T 1.00 INE442A01024 Tea & Coffee Equity
500025 ASSAMBR ASSAMBROOK LTD.-$ Delisted X 10.00 INE353C01011 Tea & Coffee Equity
500026 ATSHIND ATASH INDUSTRIES LTD. Delisted Z 10.00 NA Equity
500027 ATUL ATUL LTD. Active A 10.00 INE100A01010 Specialty Chemicals Equity
500028 ATVPR ATV PROJECTS INDIA LTD. Active XT 10.00 INE447A01015 Construction & Engineering Equity
500029 AUTOLITIND AUTOLITE (INDIA) LTD. Active B 10.00 INE448A01013 Auto Parts & Equipment Equity
Page 2...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
500030 AUTORIDFIN AUTORIDERS FINANCE LTD. Suspended T 10.00 INE450A01019 Finance (including NBFCs) Equity
500031 BAJAJELEC BAJAJ ELECTRICALS LTD.-$ Active A 2.00 INE193E01025 Household Appliances Equity
500032 BAJAJHIND Bajaj Hindusthan Sugar Limited Active B 1.00 INE306A01021 Sugar Equity

... and so on.
```